# SQL query to return only 11 digit numeric values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Actual data:

```
|31345678921|
|56789056789|
|56780345678|
|4567       |
|3456       |
|00678596   |
|03456788453|
|ASA 2344   |
|34565      |
|BBq23      |
|DNF LIMIT  |
```

Required data:

```
|31345678921|
|56789056789|
|56780345678|
|03456788453|
```

Comment: I have no idea why this question would be closed.  It seems quite clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One method is:

```
where actual not like '%[^0-9]%' and
      len(actual) = 11
```

That is, the value has no non-digits and is 11 digits long.

Another method is:

```
where try_convert(numeric(11,0), actual) between 10000000000 and 99999999999
```

That is, when converted to a numeric, the range suggests that it is 11 digits.

And a third method is:

```
where actual like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

SQL Server supports character classes with `like`, so you can just like `[0-9]` 11 times.